# Disable buffer clearing at a given cell format (NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy")

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim v
  If Target.Cells.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
  If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
  v = Target.Value
  If VarType(v) <> vbDate Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If v Like "???##" Or v Like "???-##" Then Target.Value = Left(v, Len(v) - 2) & "20" & Right(v, 2)
    If VarType(Target.Value) <> vbDate Then Target.Value = Empty
    Target.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If
End Sub
```

When copying (ex: may20, may-20) from another column to column A in Excel itself with this macro, it allows to paste only once - the next cell is no longer pasted, apparently, the clipboard is cleared after the first paste. I have to copy again from another column. How it can be corrected?

Comment: Sorry to say but the code is doing exactly what you are saying... Yu allow only for one cell as you do a cell count. Maybe you should first do some training on VBA?

Comment: Try adding `Target.Copy` before exiting if you need to keep pasting that value

Comment: @Aldert If I assign the value NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyyyyy" to a cell using a macro (as in my case), I cannot insert (ex: may20, may-20 etc) more than once. For example, the copy cell mode is cancelled if the user starts editing the cell.

Comment: @Tim Williams I need to add (ex: may20, may-20 etc.), months and years can be different. How I can do this? Could you send me a piece of code where this should be added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below - if you need to paste the same value again.

The core problem is that the change event always clears the clipboard - there's no (easy) way I'm aware of to prevent that.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const MNTH_NM As String = "[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]" 'a bit better than "???"
    Dim v
    
    If Target.Cells.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    v = Target.Value
    If Len(v) > 0 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If UCase(v) Like MNTH_NM & "##" Or UCase(v) Like MNTH_NM & "-##" Then
            v = Left(v, 3) & "-20" & Right(v, 2)
            Target.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
            Target.Value = v
            Target.Copy
        Else
            Target.ClearContents 'if doesn't match the pattern, clear it
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If 'non-zero length
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need. Only now there's another problem. Now if I try to insert with spaces (e.g. "may20 ", "aug- 20 ", "may -20 "), it converts to "20.05.2022" or "20.08.2022". Also sometimes it doesn't insert in cells ("Apr22", "Jun20"), I don't know what it's related to.

Comment: My macro was used to solve this problem: I have dates as `MonthYear`, `Month-Year` (ex: May20, May-21 etc.) but I need them to be in dd.mm.yyyy format. For example: Aug20, needs to become 01.08.2020. May-19, needs to become 01.05.2019. Jul18, needs to become 01.07.2018. Nov-17, needs to become 01.11.2017. If enter something other than `MouthYear`, `Mouth-Year`, nothing is entered in the cells - they remain empty.

Comment: You can remove any spaces in v using Replace()

Comment: I am new to macros. Can you please post a piece of code and write what and where to change?

Comment: See edit above for how to remove spaces from the cell value

Comment: Can still insert the same as this: («may20 », «aug- 20 », «may -20 », « may21»). And now allows to insert only once, the next cell does not insert any more.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is wrong? Why does the macro let me insert words with spaces?

Comment: I added a line above to remove non-breaking spaces (which can sometimes be present in content copied from a browser).  In the end though, you're fighting against Excel grabbing the value and auto-converting it before you code runs.

Comment: Try to paste (CTRL+V) one of these words with spaces in any cell of column A: «may20 », «aug- 20 », «may -20 », « may20 » - they will be converted to «01.05.2020». But the macro should not allow such input, because the words have spaces.

Comment: So if there are *any* spaces you just want to clear the cell?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said from the beginning. If enter something other than `MouthYear`, `Mouth-Year`, then nothing is entered in the cells - they remain empty.

Comment: OK - my last attempt above

Comment: Now the macro does not allow inserting words with spaces. But now there is another problem. `Target.Copy` doesn't work. Try doing the following with your macro: Copy from any cell (CTRL+C) the word `may20` and paste (CTRL+V) into any cell in column A. You will only be able to paste once.

Comment: This is the first time you’re mentioning anything other than dates.